# Retrieving the value of ng-model from Directives template to Another Html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can't retrieve the `ng-model` value of my `template-url` from my `name directive`.

**team-two.html**

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
    <div name-directive></div>
</form>
<pre>{{userForm.firstname}}</pre>
```

here i have `name-directive` inside the `form` and a `pre` tag to view as I type a value in `input text of name-directive`

**name-directive.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.input-form');

app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope: true,
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]{1,25}$/;
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: '/src/client/app/input-form/name.html'
}
});
})();
```

in here, I have a `templateUrl` *dont mind the other codes coz I think it not related to my concern.*

**name.html**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 
 your first name"
     ng-model="firstname"
     ng-minlength="2"
     ng-maxlength="20"
     required
     ng-pattern="vm.namePattern"/>
```

in here, I have a `ng-model` that I want to access which is the `firstname`..

**Edit** Note: I discovered that if I add `$viewValue` in `<pre>{{userForm.firstname.$viewValue}}</pre>` it works.. I get what I want.. But I think that it is not the exact solution for my problem..

**Edit 2** Added link to Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6glStzEq5ckZZzph2qLw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the `controllerAs` in the directive need to reference that when you are accessing variables from the html.

`ng-model="vm.firstname"`

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 
 your first name"
     ng-model="vm.firstname"
     ng-minlength="2"
     ng-maxlength="20"
     required
     ng-pattern="vm.namePattern"/>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. yeah, that also works. But my problem is in the `team-two.html` inside the `pre` tag, I can't access the `ng-model` of `name.html`