# Accessing the NG-MODEL from Directives TemplateUrl from Parent HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I will describe my problem in a simple way I can.

I had a Directive called **Directive-A** and it has a `templateUrl` named **name.html**, inside **name.html** there is a **ng-model="name"** and I want to access it from my **Parent HTML File** where the **Directive-A** is called.

If I illustrate it in a Nested Diagram will goes like this:

**Parent HTML File** -> **Directive-A** -> **name.html** -> **ng-model="name"**

**Edit**
Note: I'm trying to access it via `pre` tag. When I try to use a `<pre>{{name.$viewValue}}<pre>`, it works. But I know it is not the exact solution to my problem.

I hope there someone who can provide me an answer or idea on how to solve my problem.. I been looking for an answer for this in a long time now, and still I can't fix it..

**Edit 2** Added Link to Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6glStzEq5ckZZzph2qLw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. If your directive Directive-A is isolated then there is no way.
2. If your directive create scope then you have to modify your template like

   ```
   ng-model="someobj.name"
   ```

   and in your "Parent HTML File" controller define that someobj like below

   ```
   $scope.someobj = {}
   ```
3. If your directive is not craeteing its scope(mean shared scope) then you can simply access that variable in your "Parent HTML File".

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.. my Directive-A scope is set to true.

Can you please look at this?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491320/retrieving-the-value-of-ng-model-from-directives-template-to-another-html-file)